# How to cascade the data type of a column of a table in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, alter-table

I have a PostgreSQL database and I need to change the data type of a column. There is a view that uses that table. Is there any way to change the data type of the column without deleting the view using `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE new_type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will have to drop and re-create the view.

The `pg_get_viewdef` function that calculates the definition of a view will be helpful.

You can do the whole operation in a transaction if you don't want to expose the "view-less" state to concurrent transactions.